# Malformed Array Literal in PostgreSQL when inserting JSON Array from a CSV

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to insert a JSON Array (defined as "_json" in the table structure) to a PostgreSQL table, using a csv. This is the **insert** statement:

```
INSERT INTO "MySchema".my_table (id, main_array) values(DEFAULT, '{{"KeyA": 10,"KeyB":20},{"KeyA": 100,"KeyB":200}}');
```

Getting the following **error**:

```
ERROR: malformed array literal 
Detail: Unexpected array element.
```

Note that I generate the INSERT statement from the database itself. The node.js Sequelize code is working fine with JSON array.

Here's the csv file structure:

**mytable.csv**

```
1,{{"KeyA": 10,"KeyB":20},{"KeyA": 100,"KeyB":200}}
```

Comment: See the commas? That's your problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Your CSV line consists of 5 entries. The first is `1`, the second is `{{"KeyA": 10`, and so on. That second entry is clearly not a valid array. You will have to escape something, because as it is, your CSV is corrupt.

Comment: I understand that. That's precisely my question.

Comment: You will have to fix the data.

Comment: Can you tell me where that csv format is wrong? I've tried several combinations, but none works.

Comment: Ah. I see now that not only is the escaping wrong, but the whole thing is not valid JSON at all. At this point, it is not even clear what the resulting JSON should be...

Answer (score 1):

The correct `INSERT` statement is:

```
INSERT INTO "MySchema".my_table (id, main_array)
values (
   DEFAULT,
   '{"{\"KeyA\": 10,\"KeyB\":20}","{\"KeyA\": 100,\"KeyB\":200}"}'
);
```

The array elements are enclosed in double quotes and the double quotes in them are escaped with backslashes.

The whole thing would look much simpler if you used a JSON array instead of a PostgreSQL array:

```
INSERT INTO "MySchema".my_table (id, main_array)
values (
   DEFAULT,
   '[{"KeyA": 10, "KeyB": 20}, {"KeyA": 100, "KeyB": 200}]'
);
```

Comment: I want the resulting array in DB to be like: [{"KeyA": 10,"KeyB":20}]. And, this format is giving: malformed array literal. "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I missed that the type you are using is `json[]` rather than `json`.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Another mistake of mine: You are not loading the CSV file with `COPY`, you are actually running `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to escape simiar to Laurenz please let me know if it helps

```
[  {    \"KeyA\":10,    \"KeyB\":20  },  {  \"KeyA\":100,     \"KeyB\":200   }]
```